# When are rules of Rollback, commit and begin in mysql used?

Tags: mysql, commit, rollback

I was reading a article that saw rules rollback, commit and begin.

I don't know these rules what is used?

are there a friend that describe me?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase, with more detail.

Comment: Read here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`begin`, `commit` and `rollback` controls a *transaction*. Everything done within a transaction is either saved together (through `commit`) or not saved at all (if doing `rollback`).

This can be used if several updates are done which should only get effect if all are successful. If you wrap them in a transaction you can then commit all the changes if they are successful, or rollback all of them if any step along the way fails.

More details can be found in [Transactions in MySQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm).